# tranpose only the two outer words of three

Tags: emacs

How to transpose "foo" and "bar" in "foo and bar" in emacs with the least number of key strokes?

input:

```
foo and bar
```

output:

```
bar and foo
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way:

A numeric prefix of 0 to <kbd>M-t</kbd> will transpose the word ending after the mark with the word ending after the point.

So, if `^` is mark and `|` is point:

```
f^oo and ba|r
```

will become, after pressing <kbd>M-0 M-t</kbd>:

```
|bar and ^foo
```

So, in your example, if you are typing `foo and bar|`, the key sequence can be <kbd>C-space M-3 M-b M-0 M-t</kbd> (set mark at end of line, back 3 words to foo, transpose those words).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (starting from the beginning of the phrase): <kbd>M-t</kbd> <kbd>M-t</kbd> <kbd>M-m</kbd> <kbd>M-t</kbd>.

If there's text on the line before `foo`, replace <kbd>M-m</kbd> with <kbd>M-b</kbd> <kbd>M-b</kbd>.